# Async-Await allocations in a call chain

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

I am trying to better understand the heap allocations that happen as the result of the compiler generated code for async-await in C#.

Consider the following code:

```
static async Task OneAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OneAsync: Start");
    await TwoAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("OneAsync: End");
}

static async Task TwoAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("TwoAsync: Start");
    await ThreeAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("TwoAsync: End");
}

static async Task ThreeAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ThreeAsync: Start");
    var c = new HttpClient();
    var content = await c.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
    Console.WriteLine("Content:" + content.Substring(0, 10));
    Console.WriteLine("ThreeAsync: End");
}
```

From ILSpy
[image: From ILSpy]

Here we would have 3 `AsyncStateMachine` struct types(one for `OneAsync`, one for `TwoAsync` and one for `ThreeAsync`) generated by the compiler.

Can you please confirm if my assumptions are right?

- A call to `OneAsync` method (which in turn would call the chain until `ThreeAsync`), would result in the **3 `AsyncStateMachine` struct types** to be put on the **heap**?
- If I was NOT using HttpClient in `ThreeAsync` method and instead was just returning `Task.CompletedTask` from it, then there would be 2 `AsyncStateMachine` struct types (one for `OneAsync` and one for `TwoAsync`). In this scenario there would be **NO heap allocations of `AsyncStateMachine` struct types as the whole call chain gets executed syncrhonously?**

Comment: Look for 'eliding async/await'. And the allocations are tiny, not to worry about.

Comment: btw: you might find this easier than ILSpy manually: [your code in sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsA6AOThjIAkYYAHA4zHAVhaJQGYsAmDAGEMAb27YAbFgAcWaQHkAdnACCUAJ5KAxgAoAlEXGEMp0gE5dAImVrNOkBgDKMCAhhX9LM1nMYAKgDuAPbqWnpeRD44ljYqYQ4YAKJKACaeLAC+RBLSKHIo0kGh9hFGUWYx1sUJ2o4ubh6RJpV+/gAWCHB24QbeldixNaWOKenN2YS5svIBnd21BuUtplVWHV09iQ3uGRWmAG5uGNoYALwYKoEY9ExCADYAlnBKMH37GEcIJ8GvLzDnXwnMgAcWoLgQjyUAHNFlZ2gxGCAAPTI6HBYLQ+5wMjaYJgPYrCzWIS/eCvEBWDAAah+f1eZCcAFdgDg0Lo0AAaDDYND6ZrRQbVeZbOrJNKEyaZIA==)

Comment: @bommelding whether or not allocations are "tiny" is frankly missing the point; the size isn't the issue - the volume is. And to understand the volume, we need to understand the call frequency, which isn't presented here. However: in many cases: the allocation is *absolutely* worth avoiding, and frankly: even the stack overhead of the state machine **in the sync case** is **absolutely** wort avoiding. This nuance perhaps impacts library code more than application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have three state machines either way, because there are three async methods. The stub created by the compiler *always* creates a state machine. You'd have two if you changed `ThreeAsync` to not have the `async` modifier, and to instead just write a *regular* method that returned a completed task.

You're right about the heap allocation: the awaiters involved would all have completed by the time they were checked, so no continuations would need to be scheduled. That means there's no need for anything to be heap allocated other than (potentially) the tasks. As you're returning plain `Task` and the task would always be successful, I'd expect a cached completed task to be used as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!

Answer (score 4):

Essentially: yes on both; the state machine is generated, but does not end up on the heap unless it actually goes async. In some performance-critical scenarios where a large proportion of calls turn out to be synchronous, manually implementing the code to switch between sync and async can be advantageous:

```
static Task OneAsync()
{
    async Task Awaited(Task t)
    {
        await t;
        Console.WriteLine("OneAsync: End");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("OneAsync: Start");
    var task = TwoAsync();
    if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        return Awaited(task);
    Console.WriteLine("OneAsync: End");
    return task; // could also have used Task.CompletedTask
}
```

Note that this involves some manual duplication - in particular of the things that happen with or after the result (the `Console.WriteLine`). There are ways of reducing this, often involving even more local functions. Note also that `task.Status` is unusually expensive, and when available (.NET Core, or with `ValueTask<T>`): `IsCompletedSuccessfully` should be preferred.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the quick reply!. I love this community. Sorry I cannot accept 2 posts as answers here.